# a bijection is an injective (one-to-one) , surjective (onto) map between sets. if S = (0, 1) and T =R, find a map from S to T which is

Tags: calculus, terminology

a bijection is an injective (one-to-one) , surjective (onto) map between sets. if S = (0, 1) and T =R, find a map from S to T which is

[image]

my effort

1)

(a) f(x) = x is a one to one function but it is not an onto function as each point in R is not mapped to the domain

(b) f(x) = 1/|x| is onto function but not one to one

(c) f(x) = -cot(πx)

is that correct

any help will be appreciated

Comment: $1/|x|$ is not onto.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to (a) looks fine.

I suggest you answer (c) before doing (b). Your answer to (c) is correct. You can remove the negative sign in front, to get a simpler answer.

Then (b) is easy. You can map $(0,\frac 12)$ onto $\Bbb R$ and $[\frac 12,1)$ to anything, such as zero. This function will be defined by cases, but your problem statement does not prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

For part c), possible answers are $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x(x-1)},\;f(x)=\frac{\ln 2x}{x-1},\;$ or $f(x)=\tan((x-\frac{1}{2})\pi)$, 
which is equivalent to your answer.

For part b), possible answers are $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{(4x-1)(2x-1)(4x-3)}{x(1-x)}\;$ or

$\hspace{2.1 in}f(x)=\tan((\pi(2x-\frac{1}{2}))$ for $x\ne\frac{1}{2}$, and $f(\frac{1}{2})=0$